# Processing Forms with Paypal Framework plugin

Tags: paypal

Can I use the PayPal Framework Plugin to process a form and send the data to Paypal as a purchase. I am not even sure where to start If I can, but I want to know it this is what it is for.

Comment: Which PayPal Framework plugin are you referring to?

Comment: @songdogtech: i believe he asked about the WordPress plugin named PayPal Framework http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paypal-framework/

Comment: @bainternet, Ah, my mistake, I think you're right.

Answer (score 2):

simple answer, Yes that is the main idea behind the [PayPal Framework plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paypal-framework/) 
and to get you started take a look at the [plugin's FAQ](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paypal-framework/faq/) to get an idea of how to use it.